# JQuery get current array index position

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array and a div:

```
var urls = ["google", "yahoo", "facebook"];

<div class="yahoo"></div>
```

Is it possible to get the array index of whichever element is loaded as the div's class?

I have tried:

```
alert(urls.index());
```

and my page breaks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try `$.inArray` utility function.

```
var urls = ["google", "yahoo", "facebook"];    
var cls = $('div').attr('class');
var ind = $.inArray(cls, urls);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var urls = ["google", "yahoo", "facebook"];

var pos = getPosition(urls, 'yahoo'); //returns 1

function getPosition(arrayName,arrayItem) {
    for(var i=0;i<arrayName.length;i++){ 
        if(arrayName[i]==arrayItem)
        return i;
    }
}​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xdQhP/)