# Find element index by its text

Tags: jquery

```
<div id='xlink'>mc</div>
```

js

```
$('#next').click(function() {
var xlink = $('#xlink').html();

var links = [ 'qd', 'mc', 'vr', 'lm', 'ms', 'kl', 'yu', 'an' ];

foreach(links, element) {
     if (element.value==xlink){y = element.index};
         alert (y);

});
```

What I need:

foreach element in `links` array, if element value is equal `xlink value` then `y = index of that element`. In this case should be `1`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery get current array index position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120852/jquery-get-current-array-index-position)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the elements text to use as a key, and look it up in the array with indexOf, or more cross browser with jQuery's `$.inArray`, and it will return the index

```
$('#next').on('click', function() {
    var links = [ 'qd', 'mc', 'vr', 'lm', 'ms', 'kl', 'yu', 'an' ];
    var key   = $.trim( $('#xlink').text() );
    var y     = $.inArray(key, links);

    alert(y);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/758cT/)

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse over the links array using **links.foreach**

```
  $('#next').click(function() {
    var xlink = $('#xlink').html();

    var links = [ 'qd', 'mc', 'vr', 'lm', 'ms', 'kl', 'yu', 'an' ];

    links.forEach(function(value,index) {
          if (value==xlink){
             y =index
             alert (y);
          }
       });
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v2334/

Answer (score 1):

not need to declare this array in eventListener

```
var links = [ 'qd', 'mc', 'vr', 'lm', 'ms', 'kl', 'yu', 'an' ];
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var i = links.indexOf(
     document.getElementById('xlink').innerText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
  );
  alert(i);
})
```

*just like vanillaJS)*

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/758cT/2/)